# Significance of wakelockid value in the GCM push bundle recived

Tags: java, android, android-studio, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

What is the significance of **wakelockid value** in the GCM push bundle recived

Bundle[{from=1063958041725, message=test message, **android.support.content.wakelockid=1**, collapse_key=event68742}]

**some times it shows android.support.content.wakelockid=8 value 8 for this**

Answer (score 0):

This is because WakefulBroadcastReceiver is used, and is there to track the wake lock held when the broadcast (message) was received. You can safely ignore it, as it is used in completeWakefulIntent to stop the wake lock.

Are you using the new GcmReceiver/GcmListenerService API? I haven't seen that in the Bundle sent to my apps.